# How to split column headers & values in TSQL FOR JSON Option?

Tags: json, t-sql, web-services, for-json

I have to talk to a webservice which accept JSON-messages, but is based on a dynamics princapel. so instead of using fixed defined fields, if wants a dynamics build, based on name\values attribute.

F.E.

```
{
    "Begin": [
        {
            "name": "sysrscols",
            "value": "sysrscols"
        },
        {
            "name": "id",
            "value": "3"
        },
        {
            "name": "crdate",
            "value": "2013-03-22T15:06:57.220"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using the FOR JSON option in SQL, I get a result with column names & their values.
F.e.
Query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 so.name,so.id,so.crdate  From sysobjects so FOR JSON PATH, Root('Begin')
```

Gives as result:

```
{
    "Begin": [
        {
            "name": "sysrscols",
            "id": 3,
            "crdate": "2013-03-22T15:06:57.220"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve the first result?

Comment: FYI, as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysobjects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) tell you, you *really* shouldn't be using objects like `sys.sysobjects` any more; it's more for compatibility for SQL Server *2000* databases. It's 2021 now, and SQL Server 2000 ran out of support entirely many many years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to unpivot your data here, and then use `FOR JSON`. I use a **dirty** solution here and convert the values to a `sql_variant`; I suggest you *do **not*** do thus. Instead `CONVERT` the values to a `(n)varchar` and use the appropriate style codes where needed to get the "format" you want.

I also bring your code into the mid 2000's, as the `sys.sysobjects` system view is a compatibility view for SQL Server 2000 (as noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysobjects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)). As it's 2021, I felt it long past time you started using the "new" system objects:

```sql
SELECT V.name,
       V.value
FROM sys.objects so
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONVERT(sql_variant,so.name),N'name'),
                        (CONVERT(sql_variant,so.object_id),N'object_id'),
                        (CONVERT(sql_variant,so.create_date), N'createdate'))V([value],[name])
WHERE so.[name] = 'SomeView' --This would be the object you want
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Begin');
```

Comment: Sweet, this seems to hit the spot. Now let's see if I can create some complexer code using this setup. Thank you